# How to suggest travel destinations to user based on a user query?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, google-search

I am trying to code up a mini information retrieval system for suggesting travel destinations to users based upon the indexing I do on the data corpus, and I am using solr for coding up this search functionality, what all things should I take into consideration to approach this job, what all parameters should I be considering as significant in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too wild to answer. There are lots of concept included in searching and make recommendation (not only for travel scope). Since I have developed the project that including searching and making recommendation feature, I give you some hints.

#### Search

- What and how to index your content(searching by what), it affect the accuracy of searching.
- Search relevance measure, you can measure by `term weighting` or `string similarity` algorithm.
- Search result sorting, this is based on search relevance measure.

#### Recommendation

- You can study `Collective Intelligence` to get full concepts of recommendation.
- Learning process to update the recommendation algorithm. (machine learning or artificial intelligence).